# Vue: How to use Per-Route Guard with Vuex getter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

Similar to the way that we handle with `isAuthenticate` function to check if user has properly authenticated, I'm trying to inspect in my store.

```
const state = {
    cliente: []
};

const getters = {
    //Verificar Regra
    CHECK_CLIENTE_STATE: (state) => {
        return state.cliente
    }
}

const actions = {
    FETCH_DADOS({ commit }, obj) {
        return fetch(`http://localhost:3030/pessoas/informacao/${obj['data']}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => commit('SetCliente', data))
            .catch(error => console.log(`Fetch: ${error}`))
    }
}

const mutations = {
    SetCliente(state, cliente) {
        state.cliente = cliente
    }
}
```

login page,

```
  methods:{
    fetch(){
      this.$store.dispatch("FETCH_DADOS",{'data':'12345'})
      this.$router.push('/') 
    }
  }
```

At the first fetch click, I inspect Vuex, apparently it is working.

[image]

Routes:

```
const routes = [{
        path: '/',
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            if (store.getters.CHECK_CLIENTE_STATE == '') {
                next('/login')
            }
            next();
        },
        component: () =>
            import ('../views/Home')
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        component: () =>
            import ('../views/Login')
    }
]
```

Well, in `console.log` at the first fetch click, I receive this error, but in vuex as shown above, the store is filled.

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected when going from "/login" to
> "/" via a navigation guard.

Why just in the second click is it redirected to `home`, not in the first?

### Updating

Trying a new approach in router.js

```
path: '/',
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    console.log(!store.getters.CHECK_CLIENTE_STATE.length)
    if (!store.getters.CHECK_CLIENTE_STATE.length) {
        next('/login')
    }
    next();
},
component: () =>
    import ('../views/Home')
```

But again, the first fetch is `TRUE` and the second `FALSE`, in the second I'm redirected to /home

Comment: `dispatch()` returns a promise. Change route after the promise resolves: `this.$store.dispatch("FETCH_DADOS",{'data':'12345'}).then(() => this.$router.push('/'))`. At that point, it already committed `SetCliente`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router is being directed before the data is loaded.  Wait for it:

```js
methods:{
  async fetch(){
    await this.$store.dispatch("FETCH_DADOS",{'data':'12345'})
    this.$router.push('/') 
  }
}
```